# Replace lowercase characters with -

Tags: bash, shell

I have an output from vcfutils.pl vcf2fq with specified minimal depth, and it means that nucleotides with not enough depth are lowercase. 
I would like to change them to gaps. I could do it in higher language but I would like to know the solution in bash. 
I have found simple solution to replace all lowercase to uppercase:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{if(!/>/){print toupper($0)}else{print $1}}' in.fna > out.fna
```

but I would like to replace lowercase with -. The first row need to be omitted. Could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following `sed` command will do the trick.

`sed -e '/^[^>]/ s/[a-z]/\-/g' in.fna > out.fna`

Lines starting with `>` will be escaped and the lowercase characters will be replaced with `-` .

Comment: Thaks. I did try to do it without making new copy, but this works.

Comment: you can pipe this to `vcfutils.pl vcf2fq` output.

Answer (score 3):

You could try it with `sed`.
Replace all lower-case chars with `-` in lines not starting with `>`:

```
sed -e '/^>/!s/[a-z]/-/g' in.fa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this solution where **tr** command from linux can solve your problem:

`tail -n +2  in.fna | tr '[:lower:]' '-'`